# Declare a pointer to a property and pass it as inout param into func in Swift?

Tags: swift, parameters, reference, unsafemutablepointer, inout

I need to choose one of some properties and pass it by reference to set it inside the func. Approximate code:

```
var someProperty = [SomeClass]()
var someProperty2 = [SomeClass]()

func someFunc(someObject: inout [SomeClass]) {
    ...
    someObject = ... //
}

//usage code
let obj: [SomeClass]
if someCase {
    obj = self.someProperty
    ...
} else {
    obj = self.someProperty2
    ...
}
someFunc(&obj)
```

The problem is `obj` is cannot be used as `inout` parameter but even if I declare it as `var` then `obj` is changed but not `someProperty` or `someProperty2`.

I read that somehow I need to declare `obj` as `UnsafeMutablePointer` and there are similar questions. But I don't know how to apply them to the code above to fix only these 3 lines (without of changing the rest of code):

```
let obj: [SomeClass]
obj = self.someProperty
obj = self.someProperty2
```

How to solve this issue?

P.S. in other words I need something like `let obj: inout [SomeClass]` but it is not allowed by Swift

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `Immutable value 'obj' must not be passed inout`

Comment: Have you considered using WritableKeyPath instead of UnsafeMutablePointer? Key paths are type-safe and high-level, unlike pointers.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How I check it - I create a copy of `someProperty` modify it and try to assign it back inside `someFunc`. The result is `obj` is changed but not `someProperty`.

Comment: @DanZheng could you post an example with my code please? Maybe it solves my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion in comments, the question is intended to be specifically how to work with `UnsafeMutablePointer` to achieve the result, and less about the best way to achieve the result.

It's important that the entirety of the code from the point of acquiring the pointer to using it be scoped within `withUnsafeMutablePointer`.  Because it comes down to selecting between two arrays, and then passing one of them via an alias to `someFunc`, you don't know which pointer has to be kept live, so you have to keep them *both* live.  Otherwise your program will likely crash when Swift invalidates it.

The proper and safe way to achieve the desired effect with pointers is like this:

```swift
func pointerSolution()
{
    var sourceArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    var sourceArray2 = [5, 6]

    func someFunc(_ someArray: inout [Int]) {
        someArray.indices.forEach { someArray[$0] = 0 }
    }
    
    let someCase = true // just for the sake of compiling a concrete case

    //usage code
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &sourceArray1)
    { src1 in
        withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &sourceArray2)
        { src2 in
            // Substitute appropriate type for `Int`
            let arrayPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int]>
            if someCase {
                arrayPtr = src1
                // Some additional code that may or may not involve arrayPtr
            } else {
                arrayPtr = src2
                // Some additional code that may or may not involve arrayPtr
            }
            someFunc(&arrayPtr.pointee)
        }
    }

    print("sourceArray1 = \(sourceArray1)")
    print("sourceArray2 = \(sourceArray2)")
}
```

If you have to do this is in multiple places, or just want to clean up the syntactic bloat of nesting `withUnsafeMutablePointer` blocks, you can provide a helper function:

```swift
func withUnsafeMutablePointers<T, R>(
    to value1: inout T, 
    and value2: inout T, 
    _ body: (UnsafeMutablePointer<T>, UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) throws -> R) rethrows -> R
{
    try withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &value1)
    { ptr1 in
        try withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &value2)
        { ptr2 in
            try body(ptr1, ptr2)
        }
    }
}
```

Then where you use it, you have one level of nesting:

```swift
func pointerSolution()
{
    var sourceArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    var sourceArray2 = [5, 6]

    func someFunc(_ someArray: inout [Int]) {
        someArray.indices.forEach { someArray[$0] = 0 }
    }
    
    let someCase = true // just for the sake of compiling a concrete case

    //usage code
    withUnsafeMutablePointers(to: &sourceArray1, and: &sourceArray2)
    { src1, src2 in
        // Substitute appropriate type for `Int`
        let arrayPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int]>
        if someCase {
            arrayPtr = src1
            // Some additional code that may or may not involve arrayPtr
        } else {
            arrayPtr = src2
            // Some additional code that may or may not involve arrayPtr
        }
        someFunc(&arrayPtr.pointee)
    }

    print("sourceArray1 = \(sourceArray1)")
    print("sourceArray2 = \(sourceArray2)")
}
```

If you want to live dangerously, you *can* do this:

```swift
func dangerousPointerSolution()
{
    var sourceArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    var sourceArray2 = [5, 6]

    func someFunc(_ someArray: inout [Int]) {
        someArray.indices.forEach { someArray[$0] = 0 }
    }

    let someCase = true // just for the sake of compiling a concrete case

    //usage code
    let address: Int
    if someCase {
        address = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &sourceArray1) { Int(bitPattern: $0) }
        // Some additional code that may or may not involve address
    } else {
        address = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &sourceArray2) { Int(bitPattern: $0) }
        // Some additional code that may or may not involve address
    }
    someFunc(&(UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int]>(bitPattern: address)!).pointee)

    print("sourceArray1 = \(sourceArray1)")
    print("sourceArray2 = \(sourceArray2)")
}
```

Note the pointer conversion through `Int`.  This is because when `withUnsafeMutablePointer` returns, it invalidates the pointer `$0` internally, and if you were to just return `$0`, the pointer that is returned by `withUnsafeMutablePointer` is also invalidated.  So you have to trick `Swift` into giving you something you can use outside of `withUnsafeMutablePointer`.  By converting it to an `Int`, you're basically saving off the valid address as a numeric value.  Swift can't invalidate it.  Then outside of `withUnsafeMutablePointer` you have to convert that `Int` address back into a pointer, which `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` has an initializer to do (after all, you can imagine an embedded system with memory mapped I/O.  You'd need to read/write to a specific address to do I/O.)  Any time you have to trick the compiler into letting you do something, it should be a big red flag that maybe you shouldn't be doing that.  You may still have good reasons, but at the very least, it should cause you to question them, and consider alternatives.

It's important that you don't use `address` to reconstruct another pointer outside of this scope.  In this specific example, it remains a valid address within the function scope only because it's an address for local values that are referred to after the pointer is used.  When those values go out of scope, using any pointer to them becomes a problem.  If they were properties of a `class` letting the address escape outside of the scope of the `class` would be a problem when the instance is deinitialized.   For a `struct` the problem happens sooner since it's likely it would end up being used on a copy of the `struct` rather than on the original instance.

In short, when using pointers, keep them as local as possible, and be sure they, or anything that can be used to reconstruct them without the original Swift "object" they point to, don't escape outside the context in which you know for sure that they are valid.  This isn't C.  You don't have as much control over the lifetime of allocated memory.   Normally in Swift you don't have to worry about it, but when you do use pointers, it's actually harder to reason about their validity than it is in C for the very reason that you don't get to specify when allocated memory becomes invalid.  For example, in Swift, it's *not* guaranteed that a locally allocated instance of a class will remain "live" through the end of the scope.  In fact, it's often deinitialized immediately after its last use, even though there may be more code after in the same scope.  If you have a pointer to such an object, even when you are still the same scope, you may now be pointing to deinitialized memory.  Swift even has to provide `withExtendedLifetime` to deal with such cases.  That's why Swift tries to limit their use solely within the `withUnsafePointer` family of functions.  That's the only context that it can guarantee their validity.  There are other contexts in which they would be valid, but the compiler can't prove that they are.

Comment: It seems the first way is almost the same thing I need but I also want to try to put `let arrayPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int]>
            if someCase {` outside `withUnsafeMutablePointer` calls. In this case I could also wrap `someFunc(&arrayPtr.pointee)` inside a block.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but it would need to be `var arrayPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<[Int]>!` (implicitly unwrapped optional), otherwise you'll get a compiler error about capturing it before it is initialized.  And of course, you'd need to make sure that all uses of `arrayPtr` remain confined to `withUnsafeMutablePointer` closures.

Comment: I added a suggestion for a helper function to wrap the double `withUnsafeMutablePointer` calls.  If you only have to do it once, the double nesting at the use-site isn't too bad, but it could get annoying if you have to do in multiple other places, or even worse, if you need to extend the method to handle more than two pointers.  In that case, having a helper function makes the use-site a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was originally being dim in my reading of the question, so with an updated (and hopefully accurate) understanding, I'll re-express the question by giving concrete (and compilable) code of what I think OP wants to do, then give my solution.

I've renamed a few things to be more concrete and express their roles in the code.  Given code like this:

```swift
var sourceArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var sourceArray2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

func someFunc(_ someArray: inout [Int]) {
    someArray.indices.forEach { someArray[$0] = 0 }
}

let someCase = true // just for the sake of compiling a concrete case

//usage code
var arrayProxy: [Int]
if someCase {
    arrayProxy = sourceArray1
    // Some additional code that may or may not involve arrayProxy
} else {
    arrayProxy = sourceArray2
    // Some additional code that may or may not involve arrayProxy
}
someFunc(&arrayProxy)

print("sourceArray1 = \(sourceArray1)")
print("sourceArray2 = \(sourceArray2)")
```

the actual output is

```
sourceArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sourceArray2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

But the desired output is

```
sourceArray1 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
sourceArray2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

So that whichever source array is selected by the `if` statement is the array to be altered, and `arrayProxy`, though it may be used in later code, is not important for the purposes of the desired effect here.

I don't think pointers are the right solution here.   I think a slight design modification would be better.  What is desired is to alter one of the source arrays, so why not just do that?  My solution would be this:

```swift
var sourceArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var sourceArray2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

func someFunc(_ someArray: inout [Int]) {
    someArray.indices.forEach { someArray[$0] = 0 }
}

func caseTrue(_ someArray: inout [Int]) -> [Int]
{
    // The additional code from the if statement's `true` branch
    someFunc(&someArray)
    return someArray
}

func caseFalse(_ someArray: inout [Int]) -> [Int] {
    // The additional code from the if statement's `false` branch
    someFunc(&someArray)
    return someArray
}

let someCase = true // just for the sake of compiling a concrete case

//usage code - assuming arrayProxy is still needed for something in later code
let arrayProxy = someCase ? caseTrue(&sourceArray1) : caseFalse(&sourceArray2)

print("sourceArray1 = \(sourceArray1)")
print("sourceArray2 = \(sourceArray2)")
```

`caseTrue` and `caseFalse` can be local functions nested inside the method containing the `if` so they don't pollute code outside of the current context.

```swift
class AClass
{
    var sourceArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    var sourceArray2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
    
    init() { }
    
    func someFunc(_ someArray: inout [Int]) {
        someArray.indices.forEach { someArray[$0] = 0 }
    }

    func aMethod()
    {
        func caseTrue(_ someArray: inout [Int]) -> [Int]
        {
            // The additional code from the if statement's `true` branch
            someFunc(&someArray)
            return someArray
        }

        func caseFalse(_ someArray: inout [Int]) -> [Int] {
            // The additional code from the if statement's `false` branch
            someFunc(&someArray)
            return someArray
        }
        
        let someCase = true // just for the sake of compiling a concrete case

        //usage code - assuming arrayProxy is still needed for something in later code
        let arrayProxy = someCase ? caseTrue(&sourceArray1) : caseFalse(&sourceArray2)

        print("sourceArray1 = \(sourceArray1)")
        print("sourceArray2 = \(sourceArray2)")
    }
}
```

If the bodies of `caseTrue` and `caseFalse` depend on local variables in `aMethod`, it's not a problem.  Local functions capture variables from the surrounding context just like closures (in fact, in Swift they are basically just named closures).  So declare the functions just before you need to call them, which means there might be some code above them inside of `aMethod`.

Comment: _"you don't need an inout"_, this is only true if you only want to change the elements in the array but not if you want to change the array itself

Comment: So Ok so the bracket notation really does mean `Array<SomeClass>` and not just your way of saying "substitute class type here".?

Comment: Also if you passing in an array as `inout`, and then set it a different array, on exit it will be that new array.  And even mutating elements, because of copy-on-write, will likely create a new array, unless the parameter is the only reference to it.   But why not just return the new array, and avoid the confusion?

Comment: Updated answer based on the clarification

Comment: Remember an array is a value type.  You for the sake of what's happening, you can pretend that you're passing in an `Int` as `inout`.  If you assign another `Int` to that parameter, it will be the new `Int` on return from `someFunc`.  `Array` (and `Dictionary` and `Set` and `String`) is designed to work the same way.  If you assign a new value to the whole thing inside `someFunc` it will be that thing on exit.

Comment: Note that I am not OP

Comment: Sorry, my mistake on that :)

Comment: @ChipJarred it is not a solution. I already wrote that my code works as you wish but it is not the thing I need. I need to assign to `things` a pointer to property to set this property inside `someFunc`. Your code assigns a new value to `things` only not a pointer.
And I can't simply return value from `someFunc` to assign it later because in my case code execution order has influence

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov It seems I misunderstood your question, which is my fault because on reading it again, you do state it sufficiently clearly.   I have changed my answer to solve the actual problem.  It still does not need pointers.  I hope the revised solution is useful.

Comment: @ChipJarred at least you understood me but it is still not a solution: 1)I didn't promise that arrays have the same capacity. So the code will be more complex; 2)you choose `Int` type. Will it work via the same way as a custom class from my question? 3)finally I try to avoid the code repeating. You just take this code and wrap it into methods but the code is still repeating. In other words if there are 3 arrays you will suggest 3 methods with repeating code and etc.

Comment: 1) The sizes of the arrays is a non-issue.  It will work regardless of their sizes.  I made them same more just out of consistency.  2).  It will work with any element type.  If you like make my example generic on some type `T`.  Doesn't matter.   You didn't provide anything concrete.  `Int` is just to be illustrative.  3) The only repeated code is the call to `someFunc`, and that is exactly what is meant by not repeating code.  Give the "repeated code" a name, and call it multiple places, instead of having the actual code in multiple places.

Comment: Also if it comes down to a choice between not repeating a call to `someFunc` vs. using pointer in a language that tries hard to avoid them... I think it's obvious which is the lesser evil.  As an alternative, you could create a class-based array-like type instead of `Array`, so that the whole array is a reference.  Seems kind of like a heavy weight solution with little benefit.  It's also more code to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution but it looks strange:

```
var someProperty = [SomeClass]()
var someProperty2 = [SomeClass]()

func someFunc(someObject: inout [SomeClass]) {
    ...
    someObject = ... //
}

//usage code
let obj: UnsafeMutablePointer<[SomeClass]>
if someCase {
    obj = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &self.someProperty) { $0 }
    ...
} else {
    obj = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &self.someProperty2) { $0 }
    ...
}
someFunc(&obj.pointee)
```

So the "usage code" section is changed only. I didn't find a proper solution for some time because for example the following code produces "dangling pointer" warning:

```
obj = UnsafeMutablePointer<[SomeClass]>(&self.someProperty)
```

Also my solution sometimes causes this problem:

`Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x7f85df805fc0, but modification requires exclusive access`

Comment: But do you really need this complicated solution that sometimes doesn’t work? It’s probably means writing more code but why not use the variables directly, `someFunc(someObject: &somePropery)`. More code, less elegant but maybe also less troublesome?

Comment: I know from experience this code has a good chance of crashing.  Swift's `withUnsafeMutablePointer` functions invalidate the pointer on exit so returning $0 is problematic.  To make it work you have to convert it to an `Int` to basically preserve the valid address in the pointer, then on receiving side, reconvert the `Int` to a mutable pointer.

Comment: To make it work safely, you'd need to nest the `if`and call to `someFunc` inside nested calls to `withUnsafeMutablePointer` calls.  That way the pointers to `someProperty` and `someProperty2` remain valid all the way through the call to `someFunc`.

Comment: @ChipJarred In general the question is how to work with pointers in Swift like objc allowed but you simply suggest to avoid such situations. it doesn't suit me. If it is not possible at all then just say about it

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov If your question is actually about pointers rather than how to achieve the result, then you should revise your question to say so.    My previous comment in this thread gives the answer how do it safely.  You *must* keep the pointers valid, which means nesting `withUnsafeMutablePointer` code.  It's ugly and should not pass code review for this case in any organization.

Comment: @ChipJarred my question is about how to achieve the result with pointers (not necessary `withUnsafeMutablePointer`) but you suggest to avoid pointers at all.